# Error: no matching function for call to ‘Triangle::Triangle(double, double, double)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, перегрузка-операторов

```
class Triangle
{
private:
    double length1, length2, length3;
public:
    friend Triangle operator + (const Triangle &v1, const Triangle &v2)
    {
        return Triangle (v1.length1 + v2.length1, 
                         v1.length2 + v2.length2,
                         v1.length3 + v2.length3);
    }
};
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так, а то вроде бы типичный код, а ошибка одна и та же постоянно, если что OS Linux Ubuntu, IDE Anjuta.   Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Где конструктор с такими параметрами?

Comment: То есть нужно просто добавить конструктор с параметрами в виде трех даблов?

Comment: Это риторический вопрос?

Comment: @Laughing_Man По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Triangle
{
private:
    double length1, length2, length3;
public:
    Triangle (double a, double b, double c)
    {
    length1 = a;
    length2 = b;
    length3 = c;
    }

    friend Triangle operator + (const Triangle &v1, const Triangle &v2)
    {
        return Triangle (v1.length1 + v2.length1, 
                         v1.length2 + v2.length2,
                         v1.length3 + v2.length3);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне думается, что таки лучше написать конструктор так:

```
class Triangle
{
private:
    double length1, length2, length3;
public:
    Triangle (double a, double b, double c)
    :length1(a),length2(b),length3(c)
    {}
```